# Alias and group by

Tags: sql, firebird

I can't make this query work. I have read that aliases don't work in group by, but then how can I solve it?

```
SELECT 
 DATE_DOCU,
 (SELECT LIN FROM INVE01 WHERE INVE01.CVE_ART=MINVE01.CVE_ART) AS LINE
 FROM 
MINVE01 
GROUP BY
DATE_DOCU, LINE
```

Comment: SELECT 
 DATE_DOCU,
 (SELECT LIN FROM INVE01 WHERE INVE01.CVE_ART=MINVE01.CVE_ART) AS LINE
 FROM 
MINVE01 
GROUP BY 1,2

Answer (score 1):

You don't have aggregation function so group by is unuseful .. you should use disctinct for obtain distinct values

```
  SELECT  DISTINCT 
    DATE_DOCU,
    (SELECT LIN FROM INVE01 WHERE INVE01.CVE_ART=MINVE01.CVE_ART) AS LINE
  FROM MINVE01
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Group By which discard all the details.  Try using a CTE (common table expression) with a window function (

A CTE is like a subquery that comes before the main query   Window function is a way to group and aggregate data over a set of rows (the window).

```
;WITH myCTE (RenameColumn1, RenameColumn2, RenameColumn3)
As (
   Select x, y, min(z) over (partition by a, b) as MinZ)
)
SELECT RenameColumn1, RenameColumn2, RenameColumn3
from myCTE
Where RenameColumn3 < 100
```

If you are not familiar with CTE or Window functions look them up
and learn them.

I struggled for a long time trying use Group By to solve problems
that are a piece of cake with this technique.  To my credit (or shame) some
of this stuff was added to SQL server, after I first learned it, but now I am giving away my age.

Comment: This question is about Firebird, not about SQL Server; your query will work on Firebird 3 if the `;` at start of the `WITH` clause is removed.

Comment: I thought CTE and window functions are pretty standard?   Admittedly I've main worked with SQL server (only touched Orascal and MySQL a few of times).  I know CTE is on Oracle (with variations) and not on MySQL.  I think the OVER clause is standard, but the available functions var( Rank DenseRank, RowNumber, Sum, Average, etc) vary.  Don't know what FireBird is.  Related to FireFox?   Except in the recursive case, you can replace a CTE with a correlated subquery or a table valued function.

Comment: Yes, they are standard, and Firebird supports them (CTE since 2.5, window functions since 3.0). However, the semicolon in front of the `with` in your answer is a specific SQL Server trick (parser workaround). Firebird is an open-source DBMS that was forked from Interbase in 2000; Interbase itself has been around since the 1980s. It has nothing to do with Firefox (although it is the reason Firefox is not called Firebird).

Answer (score 0):

Another variant to achieve the same result:

```
SELECT MINVE01.DATE_DOCU, INVE01.LIN AS LINE
FROM MINVE01 left outer join INVE01 on INVE01.CVE_ART=MINVE01.CVE_ART
GROUP BY MINVE01.DATE_DOCU, INVE01.LIN
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
  M.DATE_DOCU,
  (SELECT I.LIN FROM INVE01 I WHERE I.CVE_ART = M.CVE_ART) AS LINE
FROM 
  MINVE01 M
GROUP BY
  M.DATE_DOCU, 
  M.CVE_ART
```